# Select a submenu with Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I need to navigate through a menu and select a submenu.

I'm using click element xpath as below:

```
//*[@id="gomenu68e1884541"]//nav/div/ul/li[3]/div/ul/li[2]/a
```

But it does not help me because the `id` is `dynamic` and changes every time, When I access the application

How can I navigate a **menu-> submenu**?

For more details on this, refer below mentioned image.

[image: code html]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you post your HTML of the nav?

Comment: >How can I navigate a menu> submenu? By not using dynamic id-s, direct descendent paths and indexed elements :). I.e. don't take what xpath the browser generates for you :) Give the html source in the question, or a link to publicly visible system, and we'd help you.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally got it to work (even on the third level of the menu) using these commands:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element
Sleep
Mouse Over
Click Link
```

And a mix of different xpath:

```
xpath=//*[@class="dropdown"]//a[contains(., 'Alumnos')]
xpath=//*[@class="dropdown"]/li[3]/div/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[1]/a
```

Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with Xpath. `js`, vagy `angular` etc. based websites which are generates the content dinamically simply not works. I have spent a lot of time on my previous automation project, to find a sulution for this: **building own xpath**. Means not just `Insect Element` in `Chrome` and other browsers, you have to build them by yourself, while learning how the code and website works. This the the method you should follow:

- get familiar with the front-end client's code
- learn `xpath`
- build your own xpath

You have to find out how you can reach the wanted element, without using `@id`s. Use `css classes` which are rarely changing that randomly, and find out the relations between your element. You have to use the `following-sibling` and `text()` and other less famous xpath selectors. I would suggest to you [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
to  get familiar with `xpath`. There wasn't any other way for me, but in the end I had an amazing, well formatted variable files, contains all the element's xpaths.

Comment: Have to agree, there's no other way around it but to learn the thing. Xpath is a (subset of a) language like any other, quite easy and straightforward even, and what we use in selenium/webdriver is the basic set in most cases. I can't imagine trying to program without the knowledge of a programming language. The w3c is the definite resource, but one can start off the w3school tutorial on it also.  And for the love of God, do not ever use the xpath/css gendered by the browsers :)